# (Rudin) $m(E) = 0$ for all Borel sets $E$ in $G$

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group with Haar measure $m$.

Recall that $m$ is a Haar measure on $G$ if $m$ is a non-zero regular measure on $G$ which is translation invariant.

The following is extracted from 'Fourier Analysis on Groups' by Rudin, page $2:$

> If $V$ is a non-empty open set of $G,$ then $m(V)>0.$

Proof: For if $m(V) = 0$ and $K$ is compact, finitely many translates of $V$ cover $K$ and hence $m(K) =0.$ **The regularity of $m$ then implies that $m(E) = 0$ for all Borel sets $E$ in $G,$ a contradiction.**

> Question: How to conclude using regularity of $m$ that if $m(K) = 0$ for any compact set, then $m(E) = 0$ for all Borel sets $E$ in $G$?

Recall that $\mu$ is regular if if for every Borel subset $E$ of $G,$ 
\begin{align*}
|\mu|(E) & = \sup\{|\mu|(K): K \subseteq E, K \text{ is compact} \} \\
& = \inf\{ |\mu|(O): O \supseteq E, O \text{ is open} \}.
\end{align*}

In the definition, the compact set $K$ is a subset of $E,$ while in the proof $K$ contains $V.$

Comment: You proved that $m(K)=0$ for any compact set $K$. Especially for those, which are contained in $E$.

Comment: So the compact set $K$ in the proof is arbitrary? It does not necessarily contain $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof works for arbitrary compact sets $K$. Let $x_0\in V$, then $$ K= \bigcup_{k\in K} (V+(k-x_0)).$$ Using compactness you can cover $K$ with finitely many translations of $V$ (by translation-invariance they have still measure zero). Therefore, $K$ has measure zero.

Comment: Shouldn't we start the proof by letting $E$ a Borel subset of $G$ and $K$ a compact subset of $E$? I think this is clearer to me.

Comment: Why do you want $K$ to be a subset of $E$? Of course it would work, but is not necessary.

Comment: I see. So the proof proves that if there exists a non-empty open set which has zero Haar measure, then every compact set will have zero Haar measure. Am I right?

Comment: This exactly the point

Comment: May I know how you obtain the covering equality?

Comment: Because for every $k\in K$ we have that $$k=x_0  +(k-x_0) \in \bigcup_{s\in K} (V +(s-x_0)).$$  Therefore $$ K \subseteq\bigcup_{s\in K} (V +(s-x_0)).$$